# Passing pointer by copy or by reference

Tags: c++, pointers

I'm writing a function to copy the content of a certain certain class (a 2d histogram, `TH2F*`) to another `TH2F*`. Pratically, I want be able to do

```
SafeCopy( in, out )
```

where `in` is my input `TH2F*` and `out` is my destination `TH2F*`. In particular, I want to implement `SafeCopy` in such a way to be able to work also when `out` has not been previously allocated. In a first instance I implemented the function this (wrong) way

```
void SafeCopy( const TH2F * h_in, TH2F *h_out )
{
    cout << "SafeCopy2d: output histogram address is " << h_out << endl;
    if( h_out != NULL )
    {
        cout << "SafeCopy2d: h_out has been identified as non-zero pointer\n"; 
        (*h_out) = *h_in; // I'm making use of the copy-constructor
                          // it wouldn't work if h_out == NULL 
    }
    else 
    {
        cout << "SafeCopy2d: h_out has been identified as null pointer\n";
        h_out = new TH2F( *h_in );
        cout << "SafeCopy2d: h_out address is now " << h_out << endl;
    }
}
```

And the output was

```
SafeCopy2d: output histogram address is 0x0
SafeCopy2d: h_out has been identified as null pointer
SafeCopy2d: h_out address is now 0xblahblah
```

but of course this didn't work because when exiting the function the "real" pointer h_out was still 0, because I passed it by copy and not by reference.
I changed then the prototype of the function (without changing its implementation) to

```
void SafeCopy( const TH2F * h_in, TH2F *&h_out )
```

in order to pass the h_out pointer by reference. In this latter case, something strange happens: if I call SafeCopy passing a NULL h_out I get this output:

```
SafeCopy2d: output histogram address is 0x*a non-zero value*
SafeCopy2d: h_out has been identified as non-zero pointer
```

My question is: why if I pass h_out by copy, it is correctly recognized as a NULL pointer, instead when I pass it by reference it appears as non-zero?

**edit**
This is the calling code:

```
//TH2F * h_migration is created and filled previously in the program
TH2F * h_smearedMigration;//  
for (int ntoy=0; ntoy < NTOY; ntoy++ ) {

         //matrix smearing
    SmartCopy( h_migration, h_smearedMigration ); //copy the original matrix to a temporary one
    RunToy( h_smearedMigration ); //smear the matrix
...
```

I would like to avoid something like

```
h_smearedMigration = SmartCopy( h_migration, h_smearedMigration );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, it's not clear why you're using pointers at all. Ideally you want to just hold objects directly. Then you don't need a special convention for copying:

```
TH2F RunToy(TH2F const &in);

//TH2F h_migration is created and filled previously in the program
for (int ntoy=0; ntoy < NTOY; ntoy++ ) {
    TH2F h_smearedMigration = RunToy(h_migration);
```

If `TH2F` is expensive to copy then you might implement it via something like pImple so that it can be cheap to move but still acts like a value type.

If you really do need pointers then you should use smart pointers and never owning raw pointers (owning raw pointers are pretty much guaranteed to make your code exception-unsafe, for example).

```
void RunToy(std::unique_ptr<TH2F> in_out);

void SafeCopy(TH2F const &in, std::unique_ptr<TH2F> &out)
{
    if(h_out) {
        *out = in; // copy assignment
    } else {
        out = make_unique<TH2F>(h_in); // copy construction
    }
}

for (int ntoy=0; ntoy < NTOY; ntoy++ ) {
    std::unique_ptr<TH2F> h_smearedMigration;
    SmartCopy(h_migration, h_smearedMigration);
    RunToy(h_smearedMigration );
```

Of course you generally shouldn't need a `SmartCopy` function to dynamically determine whether to use copy assignment or copy construction. You should know what you need based on whether you've already allocated the object.

```
// std::unique_ptr<TH2F> h_migration is created and filled previously in the program
for (int ntoy=0; ntoy < NTOY; ntoy++ ) {
    auto h_smearedMigration = make_unique<TH2F>(*h_migration);
    RunToy(h_smearedMigration);
```

Comment: eheh you remind me of a colleague of mine "Use smart pointers!"... anyway, thanks a lot for the suggestion, I'll keep it in mind when I'll do more complicated stuff :) for now I just switched to something more basic to solve this problem...

Comment: I wrote the OP just out of curiosity... I just didn't understand why a poiter passed by reference had a different behaviour of a pointer passed by copy

Comment: @Blackphoenix When you pass by copy the called function and the calling function have access two different objects; one of which is simply a copy of the other. The called function's modifications to its object are not visible in the calling context. However, if you can get both contexts to access the same object then modifications by one can be seen by the other.

Comment: Pointers can be looked at two ways; as an object just like any other where if you make a copy and modify the copy the the original pointer is unaffected. But a pointer also acts as a handle to another object. All pointers with the same, copied value are handles for the same objects; modifications to that other object are visible to anything that has a copy of the pointer. References are like pointers except that while pointers are an object in their own right and you can modify a pointer as well as the pointed-to object, you can never modify a reference, only the referenced object.

Comment: @Blackphoenix Also, your colleague sounds really smart ;) smart pointers, and RAII in general, is an extremely important technique in C++. Absolutely critical in C++ for reliable management of responsibilities.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't shown the calling code, but it sounds like the problem comes up from something like `SafeCopy(something, NULL)`. Yup, won't work. Pass in the pointer and return the result:

```
TH2F *SafeCopy(constTH2F *in, TH2F *out) {
    if (!out)
        out = whatever;
    *out = *in; // or whatever...
    return out;
}
```

Comment: Wait... you mean literally passing `NULL` as the second argument, not a pointer whose value is `NULL`? How could that compile?

Comment: @Beta - of course it doesn't compile (with the second argument taking a reference to pointer). As I said in the beginning, the question doesn't show the calling code. If you want details about it, ask the original poster.

Comment: My point is that this guess cannot be correct, given that the OP compiled and ran the code.

Answer (score 0):

> if I call SafeCopy passing a NULL h_out I get this output:
>   ...
>   * edit This is the calling code:
>   TH2F * h_smearedMigration;
>   ...
>      SmartCopy( h_migration, h_smearedMigration );

That's not a NULL pointer, that's an uninitialized pointer. It contains random junk, unlikely to be 0x0.

Comment: The fact is that if I pass h_smearedMigration pointer by copy it appears as a null pointer. I also checked
       //matrix smearing
        cout << h_smearedMigration << endl;
 SmartCopy( h_migration, h_smearedMigration );

And it correctly is cout'ed as 0